# ¿Cómo comparar cadenas en C?

Tags: c

El `while` me dice que la comparación no existe

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int n, e, op, edad; 
    char sexo[1], res[2]; 
    n = 0; 
    edad = 0; 
    do {
        n = n + 1; 
        printf("Edad del conductor\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &e); 
        printf("Sexo de conductor F= femenino, M= masculino\n"); 
        scanf("%s", sexo); 
        printf("1 si es capital y 2 otra parte del estado\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &op);

        if (edad < 30) {
            edad = edad + e;
        }
        printf("desea ingresar otro usuario? Si o No?\n");
        scanf("%s", res);
    } while (res != "No");

    edad = edad / n;
    printf("%d", edad);

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que en C no puedes comparar *strings* usando los operadores `==` ni `!=` estos solo van a comparar los punteros de ambos.

Debes usar una función para comparar como `strcmp`

```
#include <string.h>

// ...

} while (strcmp(res, "No") != 0)
```

La función devuelve `0` cuando son iguales.

---

A partir de tus comentarios, si necesitas manipular un caracter solo entonces no necesitas usar funciones para *string* y podrías cambiar tu programa a algo así:

```
char res;

// ...
    printf("desea ingresar otro usuario? (S)i o (N)o?\n");
    scanf(" %c", &res); // hay un espacio en blanco antes de %c para que no capture el "enter" anterior
} while (res != 'N');
```

Fíjate que ahora `res` es declarado como `char` sin `[]`.  `scanf` ahora usa el formato `%c` para leer un solo caracter y `'N'` usa comillas simples `'` no `"` para indicar que no es una cadena.

Comment: y no hay manera de hacerlo sin usar esa funcion?

Comment: Sí, podrías hacerlo recorriendo ambos *strings* a la vez y comparando carácter por carácter si son iguales.

Comment: Pero esa manera como te darás cuenta es propensa a errores y es mejor utilizar las funciones que ya están implementadas.

Comment: y me puedes decir como? es que no creo que en el examen me dejen poner eso ajajajaj

Comment: jaja, en tu curso ¿les han enseñado a manipular *strings* ? porque si eso entra en el exámen entonces es mejor que uses la manera que les haya enseñado el profesor.  La manera que te digo es bastante básica, y no se si eso lo consideren válido, algunos te dirían bien por implementarla tu mismo otros te dirían que no debiste, así que depende.

Comment: Pero si lo quieres saber por curiosidad, el algoritmo sería recorrer cada *string* como un *array* de caracteres hasta el final (el caracter nulo `\0`) comparándo si el caracter del índice [0] es igual al índice [0] de la otra, y así por cada uno.

Comment: bueno asi comparando, pero nunca lo habia hecho con cadenas, siempre con numeros

Comment: por codigo ansii tengo entendido

Comment: Entonces tal vez sería mejor que por ahora uses solamente un caracter, es más fácil de comparar y usar hasta que vean en el curso *strings* a mas detalle, te agregaré un ejemplo.

Comment: excelente seria de mucha ayuda, gracias

Comment: Listo, actualicé mi respuesta.

Comment: si salio, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es conveniente usar las funciones para esto, como :

```
int strcmp(const char *cadena1, const char *cadena2);
```

*Pero si queremos ver una matriz como tal, las matrices de forma general ...*

Las matrices en su conjunto, se comparan valor a valor, indice por indice.

---

En C, las cadenas de caracteres concluyen con el caracter '\0', el cual indica que en su posición (y desde su posición) no hay ya más caracteres en la cadena.

En caso de que queramos implementar una función en C para comparar cadenas de caracteres en arrays de caracteres, sugiero este código ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool comparaStr (char entrada[],char modelo[])
{
int ind = 0;

while (entrada[ind]!='\0' && modelo[ind]!='\0' && entrada[ind] == modelo[ind]) ind++;

if (entrada[ind]!='\0' || modelo[ind]!='\0')
   return false;

return true;
}
```

*Nota : Por cierto, a la hora de una entrada por teclado, tened en cuenta, que scanf no admite espacios, si queremos que se admitan espacios, hemos de usar* `gets(arrayDeCaracteres);`

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main( ){

    int n, e, op, edad; 
    char sexo[1], res[2]; 
    n = 0; 
    edad = 0; 
    do {
        n = n + 1; 
        printf("Edad del conductor\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &e); 
        printf("Sexo de conductor F= femenino, M= masculino\n"); 
        scanf("%s", sexo); 
        printf("1 si es capital y 2 otra parte del estado\n"); 
        scanf("%d", &op);

        if (edad < 30) {
            edad = edad + e;
        }
        printf("desea ingresar otro usuario? Si o No?\n");
        scanf("%s", res);
        
        /* +++ ingresamos el valos escrito por el susuario en res
        y validamos si continua o no, dependiendo del la rrespuesta 
        , suponiendo que Eligio No , se rompera el ciclo con BREAk; 
        
        eSPERO Y SERVIRA MI AYUDA*/
        
    
        if(res=="No") ; break;
    } while (res != "No");

    edad = edad / n;
    printf("%d", edad);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Obviamente que tu ayuda sirve, pero lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para que sepas como debes de responder, recuerda que puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/480379/edit) tu respuesta