# C++ - Comparación de Cadenas

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un procedimiento que colocando un DNI, me arroje los datos almacenados en un array de strucs.

El struct está definido de la siguiente manera:

```
struct poliza
{
    int nroPoliza;
    char dniAsegurado[11];
    char nombreAsegurado[50];
    char apellidoAsegurado[50];
    char cuotaAlDia;
    char patenteAuto[10];
    char polizaActiva;
    int cantIncidentes;
};
```

Y el método para buscar y mostrar por pantalla es el siguiente:

```
void busquedaXnroDni (poliza V[],int tam)
{
    char dni[11];
    int i;
    bool encontrado = false;
    cout << "\nIngrese el numero de DNI" << endl;
    cin >> dni;
    i = 0;
    while(encontrado == false && i < tam){
        if(dni == V[i].dniAsegurado){
            encontrado = true;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(encontrado == true){
        cout << "*******************REGISTRO " << i << "*******************" << endl;
        cout << "\nNumero: " << V[i].nroPoliza << endl;
        cout << "DNI Asegurado: " << V[i].dniAsegurado << endl;
        cout << "Nombre Asegurado: " << V[i].nombreAsegurado << endl;
        cout << "Apellido Asegurado: " << V[i].apellidoAsegurado << endl;
        cout << "Cuota al dia: " << V[i].cuotaAlDia << endl;
        cout << "Patente del auto: " << V[i].patenteAuto << endl;
        cout << "Poliza Activa: " << V[i].polizaActiva << endl;
        cout << "Cantidad de incidentse: " << V[i].cantIncidentes << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "*******************FIN DE REGISTRO*******************\n" << endl;
    } else{
        cout << "*******************REGISTRO INEXISTENTE*******************\n" << endl;
        cout << "No existe la poliza que usted busca\n";
        cout << "\n*******************FIN DEL REGISTRO*******************\n" << endl;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, una vez notado que no se debe hacer la comparación de cadena de caracteres con los operadores lógicos (== o !=) traté de usar, sin suerte la función strcmp como recomiendan en este [hilo: ¿Cómo comparar cadenas en C?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7640/c%C3%B3mo-comparar-cadenas-en-c)

Siguiendo la referencia sobre la función de la página [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) traté de replicar y ver si podía hacer uso de la función pero no puedo. El output siempre me dice "Iguales"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código es el siguiente:

```
int main()
{
    char caracteres1[] = {"4568"};
    char caracteres2[4];

    cout << "caracterse 2 ";
    cin >> caracteres2;
    if(strcmp(caracteres1, caracteres2) != 0)
        cout << "iguales";
    else
        cout << "distintas";
}
```

¿Estoy tomando mal el ingreso por consola?¿Qué se me está escapando?¿Hay una forma mejor de plantear la búsqueda secuencial del DNI?

Answer (score 2):

Estas en lo cierto strcmp es para comparar cadenas en lenguaje C pero no leiste bien la documentacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun ella cuando ambas cadenas son iguales el valor de retorno es un cero, pero en tu codigo estas indicando lo opuesto que cuando el valor sea distinto de cero te marque las cadenas como que son iguales lo cual es incorrecto.

Simplemente cambia esta linea

```
 if(strcmp(caracteres1, caracteres2) != 0)
     cout << "iguales";
```

Por esta

```
if(strcmp(caracteres1, caracteres2) == 0)
     cout << "iguales";
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor poner la descripción de la función (en Español) en lugar de una captura de pantalla (en Inglés)?

Comment: Lo noté. Sin embargo. A pesar de hacer ese cambio no arroja el output correcto. URL: https://ibb.co/k0JoOa

Comment: Si funciona mira, http://cpp.sh/3gy6z